# Mysql 5.7 will work with the JDBC "10.2.0.1.0"?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, ubuntu, jdbc

In Ubuntu 18.04, I am trying to connect JDBC and MySQL, but it is not supporting. Also I am using `Apache Tomcat 9` server.

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.29, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

JDBC `/ojdbc14/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` is,

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Specification-Title:    Oracle JDBC driver classes for use with JDK14
Sealed: true
Created-By: 1.4.2_08 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Implementation-Title:   ojdbc14.jar
Specification-Vendor:   Oracle Corporation
Specification-Version:  Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"
Implementation-Version: Oracle JDBC Driver version - "10.2.0.1.0"
Implementation-Vendor:  Oracle Corporation
Implementation-Time:    Wed Jun 22 11:19:45 2005

Name: oracle/sql/converter/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/
Sealed: false

Name: oracle/sql/converter_xcharset/
Sealed: false
```

In context.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Context>
<Resource
  name="assign8"
  auth="Container"
  type="javax.sql.DataSource"
  maxActive="1000"
  maxIdle="50"
  maxWait="10000"
  driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jerry"
  username="root"
  password="password"/>
</Context>
```

What is the correct compatibility of Mysql and JDBC? And how to fix `java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'` error here?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work. You are using an Oracle specific JDBC Driver with a MySQL database. Use a MySQL driver instead of Oracle else it will not work.

Comment: it seems that there's no class registered at all, not a driver issue

Answer (score 0):

You are apparently trying to use an Oracle JDBC driver JAR to access a MySQL database.  That won't work.

You need a MySQL Connector/J driver JAR.  You can download it from the MySQL downloads site.  The [MySQL Connector/J 8.0 Developer Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html) compatibility matrix should allow you to decide which driver version you need.

Comment: I have already installed mysql-connector and added `mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar` in STS libraries

Comment: 1) So why didn't you say that in your Question? 2) So why did you show us the manifest for `ojdbc14.jar` in the Question ... if you were already using Connector/J?  3) The driver class name for MySQL Connector/J 8.x is **different** to what you are using in the `context.xml` file.  Check the manual for the correct classname.

Comment: I was raised a question in detail but later I changed it while fixing...

Comment: You are not making much sense here.  In future, your question should contain the actual question you want answered, and the actual facts that pertain to that question.  Anyway, the answer to the question that you actually asked is that the JDBC driver with the version number in the question's title is not compatible with MySQL.